# Creating a ListView ClickOnItemList

Tags: qt, listview, qml, qt5

I'm using Qt creator, I create a basic ListView (I field the list in main.cpp), and i can see my list. How can I make a ListView Clickable event ? Like when I click on my ListItem I can do some stuff ?

```
ListView {
    anchors.fill: parent
    spacing: 5
    width: 100
    height: 200
    model: myModel
    delegate: Rectangle {
        height: mainWindows.height / 6
        width: mainWindows.width + 50
        Text {
            anchors {
                verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
            }
            text: modelData
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use [`MouseArea`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-mousearea.html):

```
ListView {
    anchors.fill: parent
    spacing: 5
    width: 100
    height: 200
    model: myModel
    delegate: Rectangle {
        height: mainWindows.height / 6
        width: mainWindows.width + 50
        Text {
            anchors {
                verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
            }
            text: modelData
            MouseArea{
                anchors.fill: parent
                onClicked: console.log(modelData)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I change it like that with OnClicked { console.debug("test"} but nothing happened..

Comment: @YPR you have used `anchors.fill: parent` inside the MouseArea, maybe you have implemented my solution incorrectly, I have tested it and it works correctly, so if the problem persists you must edit your question and indicate how you have implemented my solution and also provide a [mcve]

Comment: It works !!! Thanks for your answer, it didn't click on the text but on the colored area. I will  check for clicking on the colored area now. Thanks for your answer !!